# C# Error: 'TestApp' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments...NO BASE CLASS

Tags: c#

I'm coding these simple lines. The Compiler gives error:

> " 'TestApp.test' does not contain a constructor that takes 0
>   arguments"

on the line of the If statement.

```
using System;

public class test
{
    public int x;        
    void Evaltest()
    {
        if (this.x >3)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The test is successful.");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The test has failed.");
        }
    }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        test C1 = new test();
        C1.x = 4;                
        test C2 = new test();

        Console.WriteLine("x in C1 is {0}", C1.x);
        Console.WriteLine("x in C2 is {0}", C2.x);



    }
}
```

Why it's happening? I have no base class here. It's not an inheritance problem right??

Comment: @JonSkeet Why to add `using`?

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: To get `Console.WriteLine` to work.

Comment: @user3234632 try break it here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/xmJp9u  or try posting your fiddle with the above mentioned error

Comment: @JonSkeet I think the `using System;` enough to get `Console.WriteLine` to work.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan: Either the original post (before a 5 minute edit) didn't have the `using System;` at all, or I was confused by it not having been formatted properly. But the `using System.Console;` was a typo. Either way, with `using System;` the code works.

Comment: do you have a constructor with parameters in class test?